# Keras, layers shapes missing

Tags: keras

When I load model to Keras and print summary using:

```
model = applications.VGG16(include_top=True)
print(model.summary())
```

I can see all shapes:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 224, 224, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      1792      
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      36928     
_________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 112, 112, 64)      0         
...
```

But when I do not include top (include_top=False), I don't see shapes:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, None, None, 3)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 64)    1792      
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 64)    36928     
_________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, None, None, 64)    0         
...
```

Why is that? Or maybe it shouldn't be like that and I have some problems?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I have found an answer. Without top network can use different input sizes for different picture resolutions, and 'None' means that it can accept any shape, so if I use it like:

```
model = applications.VGG16(include_top=False, input_shape=(128, 128, 3))
```

it will calculate actual shapes for the network and print:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 128, 128, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 128, 128, 64)      1792      
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 128, 128, 64)      36928     
_________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 64, 64, 64)        0
```